# Is there an R function that let's you select two specific cities from a column of more than 10 cities?

Tags: r

I need to show the distribution of two columns which are house_price and city however, i must only select "Amsterdam" and "Rotterdam" from the city column. Is there any way I can do this please? Also, the data is imported to R as a dataset called rental from a csv file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `dfnew <- subset(df,city %in% c("Amsterdam","Rotterdam"))`

Comment: That worked however, all the columns with regards to those two cities are being displayed. I just need the column price to show up in addition to the selected cities please

Comment: Try `dfnew <- subset(df,city %in% c("Amsterdam","Rotterdam"),select = house_price)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, you're amazing!

Comment: I have added as a possible solution, so that it can help others and you can make further actions on it. Nice helping you. Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code would be:

```
#Code
dfnew <- subset(df,city %in% c("Amsterdam","Rotterdam"),select = house_price)
```